# Add this class to HTML if nth child in PHP block

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a set of case studies which vary in size. Like so:

```
   | Large | Large |
|Small | Small | Small |
   | Large | Large |
         ...
```

I'm trying to run a loop which will check if the case study is the first or second result pulled, if so, use `.case-card--large` CSS, else use the default `.case-card` CSS.

I'm unsure on how to use select classes if the loop condition is true?

In plain English: if first two results, use `.case-card--large`, then for the next three use `.case-card`, then again, use `.case-card--large` for the next two and so on.

**Here's my loop so far (incomplete):**

```
 <?php 
 $counter = 1;
 $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'case-studies') ); 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        if ($counter % 3 == 1){
            echo 'alpha';
        } else {
            echo 'omega';
        } 
    $counter++ ; 
    endwhile 
 ?>
```

Output: **alpha omega omega alpha omega**, when I need it to be **alpha alpha omega omega omega**.

**The div and CSS:**

```css
.case-card--large {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.case-card {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-card case-card--large" <?php echo tp_bg_image($background, 'full' ); ?>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>ID:
      <?php the_ID(); ?>
    </p>
    <h1>
      <?php echo $heading; ?>
    </h1>
    <p>
      <?php echo $subheading; ?>
    </p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#case-study-video">
                    Click me
                </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is a loop the right away to go about this?

Comment: Please check your first `Div` I think you have forgotten to close your `Div`

Comment: If you want the pattern to repeat every five blocks, you should do `$counter % 5` rather than `$counter % 3`.